# cancel a runnable/handler before execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have a textView that I have set an onClickListener on. When the user holds their finger down for 7 seconds and then lifts up, brings up a Dialog that fires off an intent when the positive button is clicked and cancels the operation if the negative button is clicked. I wanted a visual cue when the user had held down the textView long enough so I created a handler and a runnable that triggers after 7000ms and changes the background color of the root view slightly. It works great at first. If the user holds down for 7 seconds the background changes and you can lift your finger to present the Dialog. If you cancel, everything goes back to normal including the background color. The problem is I don't know how to cancel the handler on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP if the user has lifted their finger before 7 seconds. Here is my code:

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alert_color));
                    }
                };

                View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.admin_dialog, null);

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // get the first touch in the series
                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();


                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 7000);

                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

                    stop += System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if ((stop - start) > 7000){

                        // reset values
                        start = 0;
                        stop = 0;

                        final EditText password = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.admin_password_et);

                        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                                .setView(rootView)
                                .setTitle("Edit Configuration?")
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        int counter = 1;
                                        if(password.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("mq")){
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } else {
                                            mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong password, Access denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        dialog.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    } else {

                        // reset values
                        start = 0;
                        stop = 0;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
        mAppTitle.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

I thought the call to handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); was the answer but it didn't work. As it is now, if you press on the textView and pull your finger off before 7 seconds, the Dialog won't pop up but after 7 seconds the background color will still change. How can I cancel that operation? Do I need to implement this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual problem is that you create a new instance of Runnable every onTouch, so the removeCallback will not match the one you posted it before, a solution is this:

Declare Runnable out of the method scope and init it only on down.

Also I added ACTION_CANCEL as UP cause this behaviour can happen.

```
        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        Runnable runnable;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.admin_dialog, null);

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // get the first touch in the series
                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();


             runnable = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alert_color));
                }
            };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 7000);

            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

                stop += System.currentTimeMillis();

                if ((stop - start) > 7000){

                    // reset values
                    start = 0;
                    stop = 0;

                    final EditText password = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.admin_password_et);

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                            .setView(rootView)
                            .setTitle("Edit Configuration?")
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    int counter = 1;
                                    if(password.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("mq")){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    } else {
                                        mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong password, Access denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    dialog.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {

                    // reset values
                    start = 0;
                    stop = 0;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
    mAppTitle.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. I'm giving you credit for this answer because you correctly identified why I was having the issue. I figured that out too but I also discovered the CountDownTimer class that Android provides. Both of our solutions work but I should have explained myself better. Nice job and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try instead of using 7000 as your repeat, you could do a much smaller interval, and instead do a time diff and so in your handler you check to see if that diff has exceeded 7000ms.  Once the condition is met, then you perform your action.  Hopefully I understood your question, properly.

```
   Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (diff >7000) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    } else {
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Did you figure out what to do for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thank you for everyone's help but I figured out what I think is the best solution. I created a CountDownTimer object outside of the OnTouchListener. On MotionEven.ACTION_UP I cancelled the timer. Here is the code if it helps anyone else:

```
final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alert_color));
            }
        };

        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.admin_dialog, null);

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // get the first touch in the series
                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timer.start();

                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    timer.cancel();

                    stop += System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if ((stop - start) > 7000) {

                        // reset values
                        start = 0;
                        stop = 0;

                        final EditText password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.admin_password_et);

                        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                                .setView(rootView)
                                .setTitle("Edit Configuration?")
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        int counter = 1;
                                        if (password.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("mq")) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } else {
                                            mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Wrong password, Access denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        dialog.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    } else {

                        // reset values
                        start = 0;
                        stop = 0;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
        mAppTitle.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }
```